# Tables with same structure and other tables with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database

I want to create 3 Tables (I will call them Elements), that have nearly the same structure, and 4 tables (Informations) for each Elements that are linked with foreign keys.
The Informations have the same structure

```
CREATE TABLE Information (
     element INT UNSIGNED,
     information INT UNSIGNED,
     PRIMARY KEY (element, information),
     FOREIGN KEY element ON ElementTable(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
     FOREIGN KEY information ON InformationTable(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The problem is that i want to create a unique table for all informations instead of having 12 tables (4 for each Elements), like that :

```
CREATE TABLE Information (
     --
     element_type VARCHAR(10),
     information_type VARCHAR(10),
     --
     element INT UNSIGNED,
     information INT UNSIGNED,
     PRIMARY KEY (element, information),
     FOREIGN KEY element ON ElementTable(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
     FOREIGN KEY information ON InformationTable(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

But foreign keys don't work like that.
While searching i found "polymorphic associations" but it lose the advantages of foreign keys that can cascade and that i am using. Or is there a way to mimic cascade without the foreign keys.
Also, is this better, in term of storage and performances to have the single table i want to create or the 12 tables (And do more (?) requests) knowing that each Elements can have more than 10 Information from each types of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this

```
CREATE TABLE ElementInformation (
     element INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     information INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     element_type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
     information_type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (element, information, element_type, information_type)
 );
```

And the trigger for each Elements

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER on_delete_element
AFTER DELETE ON Element
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM ElementInformation WHERE element_type=type AND element=OLD.id;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

This works as intended, thanks @Carolina Gil.
My last question about the performance isn't answered, but it will be the same with just a few thousands elements and information i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make the insert, update and delete with triggers and the second table keep only with foreigns keys and put an identity for the primary key